# Installing swirl on linux mint

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, swirl

I am trying to install swirl in RStudio and it is not working
it reads:

```
installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘swirl’
* removing ‘/home/justin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/swirl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swirl’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp9gKFfm/downloaded_packages’

When I try to load it, it says: Error in library(swirl) : there is no package called ‘swirl’

I am running Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit 3.0.7
R version 3.2.3

Comment: did you try installing httr first? Try install.packages("httr") first and then if that is successful attempt swirl again. Non-zero exit status means it didn't install so you wont be able to load it with library(package)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it work!!

By installing `libssl-dev` package:

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`